# Solve and find the inverse of f(x)

Tags: functions, trigonometry, problem-solving

Below I have an equation that I need to solve and evaluate for $f(x)$, so that I can find the rule for $f^{-1}$$(x)$.

Solve $$ \sin^2⁡(f(x))+2x \sin⁡(f(x))+x^2=0 $$

Here is my progress:

$\frac{\sin^2(f(x))}{x}+2\sin(f(x))+x=0$

$\frac{\sin(f(x))}{x}$= $-2-\frac{x}{\sin(f(x))}$

And... I got stuck, so any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Edit: $x^2$ not $x$

Comment: Make $y=\sin(f(x))$ first

Comment: ok so:  $y^2+2xy+x^2$?

Comment: What is $(x+y)^2$?

Comment: Yep, I am dumb, its the sum of two squares. Thanks for helping!

Comment: It is easy to solve $x=-\sin(f(x))$ and from this $f^{-1}(y)=-\sin(f(f^{-1}(y))$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Welcome back ! Nice to "see" you on board. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: maybe an alias... ;-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust. May be an alien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin^2⁡(f(x))+2x\sin⁡(f(x))+x^2=0$$

$$(\sin(f(x)) +x)^2=0$$
$$\sin(f(x))=-x$$
$$f(x)=-\sin^{-1} x$$
$$ f^{-1}x = -\sin x$$

Comment: Ohhh, you used sum of two squares, right?

Comment: yes, I used the perfect square formula